# Doxygen and Mathjax. Slow navigation through HTML documentation

Tags: html, doxygen, mathjax

I have been using Doxygen (for documentation).

Also I use mathjax as my documentation has a lot of math formula.

Usually everithing runs fine but today I noticed a Really slow navigation through HTML pages (like 10 seconds or more for loading).

I discovered (using CHROME's network tool) that the problem is the http GET to the **mathjax.js** on mathjax's server.

Is this something rare, that doesn't happen often or there is a problem with mathjax server?

Is this is quite usual is there **another way** to create **latex formulas for the HTML documentation** without using internet connection?

Comment: I have never used the MathJax option with doxygen. I simply use LaTeX rendering, by setting `USE_MATHJAX=NO` in the doxygen configuration file, as described in the [doxygen manual](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/formulas.html). Is this an option for you? This method simply turns the formulas into images, which are then included in the HTML, which of course doesn't require and http GETs. You do however need to have LaTeX installed, obviously.

Comment: mmm, i have never considered that. I have latex, but I have never tried that option for the html docs. I found another option that is to instal the mathjax.js in a local server, but I couldn't try that yet

Answer (score 2):

There is an option [`MATHJAX_RELPATH`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_mathjax_relpath) that points to the directory containing `MathJax.js`. It defaults to the download location of MathJax on the web.

So just download the script (from http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js) and change the option to local directory relative to the documentation output where you placed it. The documentation even suggests it.